# CakePHP Submit Search Field during entry threw Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, autocomplete, form-submit

In my CakePHP App I have a Search field set up and working properly:

```
/* title search */

if (!empty($this->data)) {
$title = $this->data['Post']['title'];
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'and' => array(
        'Post.title LIKE' => "%$title%",
        'Post.status_id =' => '1'
    )
    )
);
$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all', $conditions));
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is adding jQuery/Ajax to submit the Form automatically during text entry and load the search results "on the fly". Either on every other character, or on time intervals ...

Most, if not all, information I find on this topic is meant for Cake 1.x and doesn't work here. The Feature I am looking for should be very similar to the Autocomplete Search Field of Cakes Documentation.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (I am new to all of this)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, there are two parts to it:
- server side (in your controllers and or models)
- client side (in your views / js library)

In the controller you need to make a function similar to what you posted. have it accept the wanted title as an argument. It would be best to return the result as a json.

In the view you need the form (obviously) and some javascript to use a ajax call to submit the query and a function to process the result.One out of the box is the jQuery UI autocomplete function
http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/